# Swift textFieldDidChangeSelection not getting called in ios 12

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, button, textfield

so i make this func which is triggered when 2 textfield reach minimum amount of text count will make the button is enabled.

it works on ios 13 and above but it wont work on ios 12....which i dont know how and why it wont work

so basicly my textFieldDidChangeSelection doenst trigger anything when i type on my textfield.....its not working on ios 12 but its working on 13 an above

i try to put some print on textFieldDidChangeSelection but nothing is print on console

this is my code

//this is my func code

```
func buttonReady() {
    if phoneNumberTextField.text!.count > 8 &&   textPinTextField.text!.count == 6{
          loginButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
          loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(string:    COLOR_RED)
          loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
          print("ahaaaa ")
      } else {
          loginButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
          loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(string: COLOR_GREY_BUTTON)
          loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(string: COLOR_GREY_TEXT), for: .normal)
          print("hmmmm ")
      }
  }
```

and i use that func in here

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == phoneNumberTextField {
        buttonReady()
        
    }
    if textField == textPinTextField {
        buttonReady()
        
    }
    
}
```

and here

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    buttonReady()
    hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
}
```

and im using SkyFloatingLabelTextFIeld for my custom textfield

i still dont get it why that func couldnt work on ios12 while it works on ios 13 and above

Answer (score 3):

Same question

You can try this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    phoneNumberTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    textPinTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    buttonReady()
    hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
}
```

than

```
    @objc func textFieldDidChange() {
    buttonReady()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out UITextField.h, you'll see:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChangeSelection:(UITextField *)textField API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0), tvos(13.0));
```

`textFieldDidChangeSelection` is only available on iOS 13.0 and greater.